# Java FileNotFoundException when running a jar file

Tags: java, jar, filenotfoundexception

In my project I load my resource using

```
getClass().getResource("/package/my_reource.file").getFile()
```

All works good when I run the project in netbeans, but if I run the jar file, I get FileNotFoundException, why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the filename. You rather need its content. So use `getResourceAsStream()` to obtain the `InputStream` and read the content from there.

Comment: getFile() returns the filename as a String rather than a File. ;)

Comment: I know that, i have tryed with getResourceAsStrem and the strem is null. Anyway, i have to fill a jasper report file, so a string path is enough. JasperFillManager.fillReport

Comment: perhaps your properties file is not on the classpath when run outside netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `InputStream` rather than `getClass().getResource("/package/my_reource.file").getFile()`

You should use

```
getClass.getResourceAsStream("/package/myresource.file")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your jar. I believe that your file is not there. 
The reasons depend on how are you creating your jar. If you are doing it using netbeans, check your settings. Probably it includes only *.class files? The same is about ant. Check  tag.

Comment: Thank you, but the file are into the jar package!

Answer (score 0):

The getFile() returns the file path portion of the URL returned by getResource()
So if its in the Jar, you have to read the jar to gett he file.  If its on the filesystem you can read using FileInputStream.

If you want to get the InputStream and you don't create where you get it from use getResourceAsStream()